# Linking Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java, and I'm dealing with arrays. I have two arrays and would like to link them so that the elements in the second array correspond to those in the first. That way, I can search an element in the first array and display the corresponding value in the second array.

```
short[] Years = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012};

String[] Months = {"January", "February", "June", "January", "March", "June", "July", "August", "September", "March", "November", "March", "June"};
```

I'm trying to link it so that when I search March, for example, it displays `2004, 2009, 2011`

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : months)
{
    if(s.equals(term))
    {
        results.add(s);
    }
}
if (results.size() > 0)
{
    System.out.println("The month " + term + "appears " + results.size() + " times");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Your search for " + term + " did not return any results");
}
```

I have this code to show how many times a month appears, I just need it to print out the years after this.

Comment: So you just want to copy an array then? You might want to reword this question

Comment: Don't use 2 arrays. Instead create a custom object that contains the two properties. Then you can add the object to a single array.

Comment: The "link" between the two arrays can be delegated to the data structure itself.  That is exactly what a Map does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
short[] Years = { 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
        2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 };
String[] Months = { "January", "February", "June", "January", "March",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "March", "November",
        "March", "June" };

String term = "March";
List<Short> indexes = new ArrayList<Short>();
for (int i = 0; i < Months.length; i++) {
    String string = Months[i];
    if (term.equals(string)) {
        indexes.add(Years[i]);
    }

}

for (Short short1 : indexes) {
    System.out.print(short1);
}
```

Update:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    short[] Years = { 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
            2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 };
    String[] Months = { "January", "February", "June", "January", "March",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "March", "November",
            "March", "June" };

    String term = keyboard.next();

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : Months) {
        if (s.equals(term)) {
            results.add(s);
        }
    }
    if (results.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("The month " + term + "appears "
                + results.size() + " times");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your search for " + term
                + " did not return any results");
    }

    List<Short> indexes = new ArrayList<Short>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Months.length; i++) {
        String string = Months[i];
        if (term.equals(string)) {
            indexes.add(Years[i]);
        }

    }

    for (Short short1 : indexes) {
        System.out.print(short1);
    }
}
```

It gives me the following output for input `March`

```
The month Marchappears 3 times
200420092011
```

Comment: With my program im getting the user to enter the term

Comment: Assign whatever value is entered by the user to the variable `term` and it should be fine

Comment: Do you mean assign the keyboard to it?

Comment: The input method "Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);"

Comment: i have that part as String term = keyboard.next();

Comment: instead of String term = "March"

Comment: yea it works when i run it separately, but when i incorporate it in my code it doesnt

Comment: @user2297518 what was the problem

Comment: for (Short short1 : indexes) {
        System.out.print(short1);

Comment: for some reason i didnt add that. my mistake

Answer (score 3):

That's an "associative array" or a "map".  Here is a Java example.

```
Map<String, String> userEmails = new HashMap<String, String>();
userEmails.put("Tony", "tony@metal.com");
userEmails.put("Ozzy", "ozzy@metal.com");
```

Let's find Ozzy and print his email address:

```
System.out.println(userEmails.get("Ozzy"));
```

[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is the interface.  It has operations "put" and "get".  [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a popular implementation of "Map" in which the map keys (the usernames) have unique hashcodes.

Comment: He wants to "search an element in the first array and display the corresponding value in the second array".  Seems like a job for Map.

Comment: i'm not sure how maps work though. like i said im new to java and i haven't been taught that

Comment: Yes it's a shame they teach languages before basic data structures these days.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my code, I explained all of what I did.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetPrice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // You can add any number of elements in both the arrays. The lengths 
        // should, of course, be the same for both the arrays.

        String items[] = { "pizza", "cheesebread", "stromboli" };
        double prices[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };

        // What we need to do is, once the user inputs the item, we need to
        // search the string and find the index. As the prices are in the
        // corresponding indices on the other array, we can just use the index
        // number to get the price from the other array. So we just use the same
        // index but on a different array.

        System.out.println("Choose from the following, to get the price: ");
        for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
            System.out.println(items[index]);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the item: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputItem = input.next();

        for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            if (items[index].equals(inputItem.toLowerCa… {
                System.out.println("Price for '" + items[index] + "' is: " + prices[index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run it, it just skips that